# Playwright reload page after navigation if certain status code

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I am in a situation where I need my functional browser tests to check the returned status code of all page responses, and if I get a 503, attempt to reload the page X number of times before failing.

I have attempted to use Playwright network events, but it seems that altering the Page state (i.e. triggering a reload) breaks any future interaction and you end up with `Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.` errors.

For example:

```
page.on('response', async (response) => {
  if (response.request().resourceType() !== 'document') return;

  if (response.status() === 503) {
    await page.reload();
  }
}
```

(I have ommitted the retry attempts logic for simlicity)

After this code has executed, any attempts to interact with the page will result in the `Execution context was destroyed` error.

I'm not 100% sure this is the right way to approach this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting scenario. If `response` was available at [BrowserContext](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.3.0&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=class-browsercontext), your approach would work. Since that is not the case, "reload" needs to be done via opening a new page.

This can be achieved with a helper method that "returns page after retries". This method would retry page creation and navigation for error status code.

```js
const {chromium} = require('playwright');

const pageAfterRetries = async (context, url, maxRetries) => {
    if (!maxRetries) return;

    const page = await context.newPage();
    const [_, response] = await Promise.all([
        page.goto(url),
        page.waitForEvent('response', response => response.request().resourceType() === 'document')
    ]);
    if (response.status() === 503) {
        // Retry if this happens
        await page.close();
        return pageAfterRetries(context, url, maxRetries - 1);
    }
    return page;
}

(async() => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({headless: false});
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await pageAfterRetries(context, 'https://www.google.com', 3);

    // Use page for remaining script
    console.log(page);
})();
```

Comment: Yes this works for logic where I am performing a hard navigation, i.e. doing a `page.goto(url)` type call. It doesn't work for navigations that occur due to user action like clicking a link. I'm trying to do a 'catch all' type method for retrying these page loads, but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: @arjunattam can you answer my question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601470/why-playwright-is-loading-a-next-page-on-navigation-without-executing-next-code?msclkid=d7086a4aab6911ecaecaeb12101f7adc

Answer (score 3):

For me this part only was needed when searching for how to reload the page with Playwright:

```
await page.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working fine to me when I have written

`await page.reload({waitUntil:'load'});`